# fixing url id access

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I have this url in my PHP project, that help user to see his income and outcome at a specific date, the code I am using is PDO, and in this image, I have the data of id=18, but when I changed it to see if injections are possibe, from 18 to another id value, it works and give me data of this ID. I am only sending the username in session.

[image]

[image]

I have this PHP PDO code:

```
<?php
require_once('../include/inner_global.php');
$id=$_REQUEST['id'];
$hostdb="localhost";
$namedb="architect";
$userdb="root";
$passdb="root";
$d = "";
$result1 = 0;
$result2 = 0;
$result3 = 0;
$result4 = 0;
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostdb; dbname=$namedb", $userdb, $passdb);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
if(isset($_POST['submitDate'])){
if(!isset($_POST['Date'])){
    echo "No date selected";    
}else{
echo $d = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($_POST['Date']));
}

//Workers Table:
    $sql1= "SELECT SUM(total_pay) AS total_w FROM workers WHERE date_of_pay = :d1 AND projects_id = :id";
    $stmt1 = $conn->prepare($sql1);

    $stmt1->bindValue(":d1", $d);
    $stmt1->bindValue(":id", $id);
    $count1 = $stmt1->execute();
    $result1 = $stmt1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    ...
```

And this query is displayed in html table:

```
<tr>
<?php if($result1['total_w'] === null):?>
<td align="center">لا يوجد تكاليف عمال في هذا التاريخ</td>
<?php else: ?>
<td align="center">
<?php 
{
        echo $result1['total_w'];
}
?>
<?php endif; ?>
</td>
```

**What I want to fix, is when we are in project id = N, I dont wont the user to acces the data of project id = M, unless he logged out, and then logged in again , then choose the project with id = m, to see it**

Comment: try to encode your id `base64_encode`

Comment: If the user is logged in then you set a session variable with username I presume, se that mecanism to set the ID of the project and then use the session var `id` rather than the POSTed `id`

Comment: So, you know what user is logged in from the data in your session. **Then add checks that confirm that the logged in user is the owner of the data/is privileged to see the data.** That's simple permission checking you need to implement.

Comment: @RamRaider so how can I transform my code into sending the id by session rather than by url ?

Comment: @deceze I didn't know what you mean

Comment: @raveenanigam so I just make `$id = base64_encode($id)` ?

Comment: @raveenanigam Please don't suggest such nonsense, it doesn't help at all. OP needs **permission checking**. `if ($_SESSION['user'] != /* owner of project */) { echo 'not allowed'; exit; }`

Comment: Why @raveenanigam method isn't allowed ?

Comment: Because it doesn't protect anything. It merely obscures the id, but base64 encoding it pretty obvious and anyone can base64 encode some id and put it into a URL.